# Force all lines HTML content (with embedded element) to fill width of container

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a piece of HTML content such as:

```
<span class="wrappable"><i>(03/10/2016) Author Name</i> LongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreakLongContentWithoutLineBreak</span>
```

The "wrappable" css class is defined as:

```
.wrappable
{
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Please refer to https://jsfiddle.net/dn9tt26e/ run the fiddle.

At least in Firefox version 45.0.1, this produces an output that breaks on the first line without the line filling the width of its container. For pure text content, there is no such issue, but as soon as I add an embedded HTML element, seems the issue appears.

How do I ensure all lines (excepts perhaps the last) fill the full width of the container without breaking prematurely?

Some pictures of what I see in my browser:

1. Suggested solution using break-word:all https://jsfiddle.net/4bu8ctt4/ in Firefox:
   [image: jsFiddle in Firefox]
2. Local page on my machine in Firefox:
   [image]
3. Local page in IE 11 (this one does not wrap the second line at all)
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have basically 2 words combined with break-word, which means it'll put any long word in new line. Try with `word-break: break-all;`
https://jsfiddle.net/4bu8ctt4/

Comment: This does not seem to work. See the edited question for an image of what I see

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap

It seems that firefox and Edge don't fully support word-wrapping right now. You'll have to find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry if i misunderstood you, but maybe this helps?

add property to your class

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

like this

```
.wrappable
{
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
    display: inline !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

source:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: but that rule is already in my style. Did you see this line: word-wrap: break-word !important; ?

Comment: Do you need
*Author name* to be on the same line with this long text?

Comment: Yes, but if the *Author Name* is at the end of a line, I have no problem with wrapping content that follows. Basically I don't care where the content wraps as long as all its lines wrap only when they have filled the width of the container